# ParallelStream and Spring Async

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a list with huge data and i want to do some calculations/logic on each item.

It's calling a spring Service method to do the logic. and i was bit confused about which is the correct way to do it the fastest with async.

Right now i am just calling the method via parrallelStream like below

```
items.getItems().parallelStream().forEach(item -> addItem(item));
```

But i am still seeing performance issues, its not fully being async/fast
and i think its due to the method not being async as there is only 1 bean 1 method handling everything.

and i was wondering if adding Async to the method would improve the the performance.
or is it the correct way to go about it. and if i add async to the method should i replace the parrallelStreams with just streams?

Or is there a better way to improve the performance.

[edit]

To make the issue more clear, a user calls an endpoint with a large list and i want to do a business logic on the items and return the updated list.

Comment: Ah the idea that throwing more threads at a problem will make it faster. depending on your size of data, the type of data en type of processing you do, this might even be slower then with a single thread. Creating threads, syncing them takes time and resources.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a singleton bean with method that implements business logic on the single item.
2. Create a queue
3. Create a Spring Scheduler that periodically takes one item from the queue and async run the bean to process it.

In general you should prefer to use Spring features for async calculation to java features.

In case the list is huge do not forget about http call timeout which is usually 30 sec.

In case the calculation takes longer, your REST API should accept the list, create a task and retrieve http status 203_ACCEPTED and do task in the separate thread.

Comment: So use normal Stream and Async?

Comment: In this case do not use stream at all. Put all item to the query and parallel scheduler

Comment: I am sorry i think i posed my question wrong, In my case a user call the Rest endpoint with a large list that i want to do business logic on and return the result. so introducing a queue and scheduling is bit confusing.

Comment: It is the same. The client should get the large list and put it into the queue to not hold the process like you do in the example.